# How to remove specific database permissions using query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I am giving the permissions as per given query.

Now I want to remove test1 DB from user test.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::test TO test;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::test1 TO test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign ownership back to `dbo` which is default owner of the database.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::test1 TO dbo
```

OR

You can give the ownership to whom you want to assign instead of giving it to `dbo`.

Comment: if I have 4 users in test1, in that case, remove DB rights from all users?

Comment: Try `USE DATABASE_NAME; REVOKE ALL FROM USER_NAME`. It will revoke all permissions of a user from the Database. Follow the below link for more info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/revoke-database-permissions-transact-sql